# Billboarding effect in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, graphics, glut

How would I conceptualize getting an image to always face a camera. I tried using trigonometry with arctan and the distances from the camera to the images, however this did not seem very graceful. It also set a bound on how for the image can rotate. Is there a better way to go about billboarding?

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 type of billboards, by angles involved:

- face camera by 1 axis - usually used as trees in older games, if you look at them from straight up height they will "disappear";
- face camera by 2 axis and rotate around themselves in remaining 1 axis - those are usually used for particles (smoke, fire, stars);
- face camera by 2 axis and follow camera's roll(bank) - those are usually used for ingame texts and captions.

As you might have already noticed - everything is about rotation, if billboard matches the camera angles. Do you have a Camera object with distinct orientation? If yes - you just take the angles and use them (billboard should face the camera, not mimic it, so the normal direction gonna be inversed (when camera faces north, billboard faces the opposite - south)). If no - you should get a Camera.